# pylint plugin config in Code Climate configuration for GitlabCI code_quality job

Tags: gitlab, dependencies, gitlab-ci, pylint, code-climate

If someone already used some custom Code Climate configuration for GitlabCI code_quality job, Especially implementing pylint scanner.
I would be grateful if you could share how you work around the issue with pylint reporting `Critical - Unable to import '...'` due to not installed Python dependencies.

The code is Airflow DAGs code.
CC config:

```yaml
version: "2"
plugins:
  pylint:
    enabled: true
```

Example of items in the report:

```
Code Quality scans found 555 new findings.

Critical - Unable to import 'airflow.models'
in composer/dags/dag0/ingest/some_api_ingest.py:5

Critical - Unable to import 'pandas'
in composer/dags/dag1/ingest/bq_common.py:6

Critical - Unable to import 'pandas'
in composer/dags/dag2/ingest/bq_common.py:6
```

requirements.txt is in the root of the repo

Comment: What's the exact error? Can you share your `.codeclimate.yml` file?

Comment: @sytech This is not an error but new findings in the final Code Quality report. I've updated the message body with config and examples of findings.